# i only want to display posts created by user in index page in my rails app instead of all posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

This is my posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @post = Post.all
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(set_post)
        @post.user_id = current_user.id

        if @post.save
            redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else
            redirect_to new_post_path
        end
    end
```

My models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x400#" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage 
       \/.*\Z/
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    has_many :posts
end
```

Now what I have to do is in my index action where there are all posts I need only the post of user who created it, so when user gets logged in he 
should be redirected to his own posts instead of all posts. I am new to rails, any suggestion would be appreciated. I don't know what to put in index and what to add in views. I have used Devise

Comment: Have you considered changing `Post.all` to some more appropriate query, since it so happens that the form requires user auth anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your controller's index method.

```
def index
  @posts = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

This will give you an array of posts belonging to the user logged in. And one more thing, please rename the object in index from 'post' to 'posts' since the result is not a single post.

Answer (score 2):

This would do that:

```
def index
  @post = current_user.posts
end
```